# I cannot do a headless test on some page while using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless, webautomation

I want to use Selenium on this page : https://id.hm.com

without the headless-mode everything works fine with that code:

```
package webautomation.portofolio;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import utils.HardWaitUtils;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;


/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class LoginPositiveTest extends BaseWebTestHeadless {
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void registered_user_able_addtocart() {
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://id.hm.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel header']//li[@class='authorization-link join hm-sign-in']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel header']//input[@id='popup-email']")).sendKeys("generator1@gmail.com"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel header']//input[@id='popup-pass']")).sendKeys("4ll574R!"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel header']//span[contains(text(),'Masuk')]")).click();
        HardWaitUtils.hardWait(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys("celana cargo"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Pencarian']")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor scroll = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        scroll.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Cotton cargo joggers']")).click();
        scroll.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='picker-1']//button[@type='button']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='size937']//button[@class='option']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='product-addtocart-button']")).click();
        scroll.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-300)");
        HardWaitUtils.hardWait(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='action showcart2']//span[@class='text'][normalize-space()='Tas Belanja']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Lanjut ke Pembayaran']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='step-title icon-valid']")).getText();
    }
  
}
```

But when I extends to headless test, the headless didnot working, code still open chrome browser.

in headless class I use this code :

```
package webautomation.portofolio;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BaseWebTestHeadless {  
    ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait> explicitWait = new ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait>();

@BeforeMethod
public void createChromeDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable gpu","--windowsize=1920,1200");
    driver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
    explicitWait.set(new WebDriverWait(driver.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(60)));
    driver.get().get("https://id.hm.com/");
    
    
}

@AfterMethod
public void quitChromeDriver() {
     driver.get().quit();
    
}

}
```

but when I change the URL to : http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login the code works fine even the headless.

why can this happen? any of you who have been face with the same problem?

I use  java for this code

Comment: what is the error that you are receiving ?

Comment: my error is I cannot do headless automation. my code always open chrome everytime i run the code

Answer (score 0):

Seem you use the wrong argument for window size

use **--window-size** instead of **--windowsize**

**--headless** without **--window-size** may make element not found

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately my code still open chrome

Comment: is your size display right?
I run your code and it just displays the default browser size. When execute with --headless, it mean no size set